# I am missing the server folder in my fresh nuxt install, and no longer have the option to choose an express server

Tags: express, nuxt.js

I am using [this](https://dev.to/kiritchoukc/deploy-nuxt-on-firebase-4ad8) guide to to have my SSR application running on Firebase. In the guide he references a server/index.js which he points to with his dev command. But my server folder is missing, and I noticed that more people in the comments were talking about this. And they said that when installing nuxt you have the option to install it with express. But I did not have such an option when installing it with

```
npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

Which I got from [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/)

So how can I use a express server (which I need because firebase uses it under the hood as well)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following someone's blog. Make sure you're using the same version. This might be happening because of use of different verison.